# Using .onKeyUp and .onChange with Javascript DOM objects

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I'm having a weird problem with some JavaScript/DOM code I've been playing with. I'm trying to assign the `.onKeyUp` and `.onChange` events/methods to a text input like so:

```
form.elements["article"].onkeyup = "alert('test');";
```

Oddly, assigning using that method is doing nothing, and I'm forced to do this manually using:

```
form.elements["article"].setAttribute("onkeyup", "alert('test');");
```

Am I missing something here? I've used the first method I mentioned before and it has worked fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
form.elements["article"].onkeyup = function() { alert("test"); };
```

Steve

Answer (score 7):

You need to assign a function, not a string. For example:

```
form.elements["article"].onkeyup = function(){alert('test');};
```

The only things I know that will take a string and eval it (other than `eval`) are `setTimeout` and `setInterval`.